# Swift: what does swift_retainUnowned mean?

Tags: swift, ios8

I do get crashlogs like the following:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x00000001006e6c78 swift_retainUnowned + 50
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x00000001006f2b3c swift_unknownRetainUnowned + 316
```

That crash seems to appear here

```
self.customPicker.cancelBlock = {[unowned self] in
    self.setCustomPickerVisibility(show:false, textField:nil)
}
```

I have no idea what this means or how this can happen. I would assume self can't be deallocated at this point, so it should be safe to call that closure.

Comment: *"I would assume self can't be deallocated at this point"* – From the crash I would assume that it *has* been deallocated when the closure is executed (and you could check it easily by overriding `deinit`). Is there any reason not to use a *weak* reference?

Comment: but the cancelBlock is only executed when pressing a button on the view. And if the view itself doesn't exist any more, the button can't be pressed, that's why I made that assumption. Nothing speaks against using ```weak``` but I would love to understand what's going on here...

Comment: Check it yourself by overriding deinit. Update your question with the result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug, it appears in Crashlytics; not very often, but it does...